Writing a component with a generic type props in typescript react
so i'm trying to write a component that renders all the fields in an object, however the object can be various types.
i.e
interface BakeryMenu {
    breads: string[]
    hotDrinks: string[]
    sandwiches:string[]
}

interface carServiceMenu {
    baseRate: string
    tires: string
    lights: string
}

and the menu renders as follows
const renderMenu = {props: BakeryMenu| carServiceMenu} => {
    //loop through the props and rendering it 
}

I want to have a generic type so that i don't need to use the | symbol in the render component. I'm also wondering if it is good practice to use a generic type in a component.
I have written a generic type component for this. It looks something like

interface menu<T> {
    menu:T
}

const renderMenu = <T,>(props: menu<T>) => {
// loop through props and rendering it 
}

I'm actually a little confused with the syntax, can someone explain what does the <T,> mean in const renderMenu = <T,>(props: menu<T>) and what are we type defining with <T,> in front of the bracket like is it the component that we are type defining?

The <T,> (or <T>, for that matter) is used to declare a generic type parameter. It's a bit of a strange syntax, but that's exactly the same as in :
function renderMenu<T>(props: menu<T>) { 
    /* */
}

Only there you're using an anonymous function, so the <T> gets split.
Now for the problem you're trying to solve. Type parameters are used to tell "that's a type, but I don't know (and don't care) which one". For example, if you were to write a filter function, you could declare it like so :
function filter<T>(array: T[], f: (x: T) => boolean): T[] { /* */ }

T could be anything (string, number, or even a custom type), but it matters than f takes a parameter of the same type than the ones located in array.
One way to check you used it correctly is to replace T with whatever type you'd like and check it still makes sense.
Let's do this with your code :
Replacing T with some menu (say, BakeryMenu), we get :
const renderMenu = (props: menu<BakeryMenu>) => { /* */ }

And replacing menu with its definition :
const renderMenu = (props: { menu: BakeryMenu }) => { /* */ }

Which isn't what you want. So first step is to remove menu<T> and replace it with T, so you have :
const renderMenu = (props: BakeryMenu) => { 
    // Sample code
    for (let name in props) {
         let value = props[name]
         // Do something with name and value
    }
}

Next, you notice that T doesn't relate anything here : it appears only once, therefore you could replace it with unknown without loosing any info.
const renderMenu = (props: unknown) => {
     // Sample code
    for (let name in props) {
         let value = props[name]
         // Do something with name and value
    }
}

And there you go ! You can now write the body of your function, rendering any prop that appear in props, and therefore any menu you pass in.
